# Python selenium tests for django throw "Address already in use" at "setUpClass"

Tags: python, django, selenium

I have a selenium tests for my django project. The base class for Selenium tests have following methods:

```
from django.test import TestCase, LiveServerTestCase

from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

class BaseTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.aux_model = models.Sample.objects.create(name='test', value=123)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.aux_model.delete()

class BaseSeleniumTestCase(BaseTestCase, LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
        cls.display.start()
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        cls.driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
        super(BaseSeleniumTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
        cls.display.stop()
        super(BaseSeleniumTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()
```

I run test on ubuntu 14.04 server virtualbox. And I constantly get a failed tests, that is not connected to any particular test

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/base/tests/base.py", line 106, in setUpClass
    super(BaseSeleniumTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1187, in setUpClass
    raise cls.server_thread.error
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

This happens only when selenium tests are running.

I run test with option --liveserver=localhost:9000-9300

I use django 1.6.1, python 2.7.6

How can I investigate root cause of this problem?

Comment: What is `BaseTestCase`? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, not sure would help, but take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619846/djangos-liveservertestcase-always-fails-due-to-conflicting-address-despite-a.

Comment: @alecxe ```BaseTestCase``` is a test case where I set up some auxiliary data. It is inherited from TestCase class and works mainly with django models. Could it be a problem?

Comment: is the live server address already in use by another web app/service? does this happen to every test or only some tests?

Comment: No, it is not in use by another web/app, It happens even on my dev computer. It happens only for some tests